# How to not crash your app on quit when using concurrency

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, nsoperation

I'm using `NSOperationQueue` and a subclass of `NSOperation` for a part in my app that is generating a lot of data and therefore is very calculation-heavy.

When the app is closed by the user `processingQueue.cancelAllOperations()` is called. Also in my `NSOperation` subclass I overwrote `cancel()` to let it forward a cancel request to the class that does the actual heavy lifting ...

```
override func cancel() {
    AppDelegate.instance.cancelDataGeneration()
    super.cancel()
}
```

But this is still not enough. When I close the app while the data generation is ongoing it will crash in Xcode.

What can I do to prevent the crashing (which might result in data loss)? Is it OK to let the app wait for closing until all concurrent operations are canceled and how is this done (if it's even possible)? Or what other methods are generally used to address this issue?

---

**UPDATE:**

After more investigation I found that `cancel()` on my `NSOperation` subclass is never called, even after calling `processingQueue.cancelAllOperations()` in `applicationShouldTerminate`. So I added a method to manually call cancel on it:

```
func cancelDataGeneration() {
    if let op = AppDelegate.instance._operation {
        op.cancel();
    }
}
```

And I call this from inside `applicationShouldTerminate` (since `applicationShouldTerminate` is called earlier than `applicationWillTerminate`. Interestingly, since my AppDelegate is a Singleton I have to use `AppDelegate.instance._operation`. If I only check for `_operation` it results in being `nil` when called from `applicationShouldTerminate`. Would be interesting to know why this is the case.

In any case, canceling now works properly: When the app is quit, it will cancel the data generation class and exits without crashing ... mostly anyway. But I still wonder why my `NSOperation` subclass' `cancel()` isn't called when I use `processingQueue.cancelAllOperations()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/cancelAllOperations).

> Canceling the operations does not automatically remove them from the queue or stop those that are currently executing. For operations that are queued and waiting execution, the queue must still attempt to execute the operation before recognizing that it is canceled and moving it to the finished state.

I would block the App's mainthread until the NSOperationQueue finishes all of its work.

I would call `[NSOperationQueue cancelAllOperations]` first.

Then in the 'Application will terminate' method I will call
[[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished). This will make sure the currently executing block(all the other queued tasks will be cancelled) will complete before the application quits.

Now if you are not comfortable with the main thread `blocking` until the currently executing block finishes, then you need to check for a flag(or an `NSApplicationDelegate` could be set on that class) which signals if the application is still active in order to continue. If application is to be terminated, then `fall out` of the block `voluntarily`, this is the cleanest way to do it.

Something roughly like the below.

```
void ^(aBlock)(void) = ^void(void)
{
    for(NSUInteger i = 0;i < 1000; i++)
    {
        // heavy processing code. Taking several iterations each second
        // At the start of each iteration, check for a flag, to see if to quit
        if(_applicationIsShuttingDown) break;

        // perform block operation
    }
};
```

and your class is an NSApplicationDelegate and implements

```
-applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    _applicationIsShuttingDown = YES;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the quick solution! calling cancelNameGeneration() and then waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished() invoked by AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate() actually does the trick! Neat! This works for me as the heavy processing can be canceled quick enough so no need for the additional checking.

Comment: Seems I've been to quick concluding the issue but my app still crashes sometimes, other times not, when quitting, even when blocking the main thread. How do I `fall out` of the block `voluntarily`? Can you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: @hexagonstar I updated my code. Can you verify the crash because of the extra threads? Since if you block the main threads, allow the newly created ones to die, then quit the application, it isn't probably what is causing it.

Comment: Thanks for the update @lead_the_zeppelin! I do something similar like your above code. I call cancel on my data generation class and it trickles down cancel to any of it's sub modules. So in every loop of all those classes I check for `canceled = true` at the beginning and break the loop if true. I call the `cancel()` on my data generation class in the `cancel()` method of my `NSOperation` subclass. But what I found now is that this cancel method is actually never called. I'm now trying to figure out why.